How many planar rotations do I need to represent an $n\times n$ rotation?
Suppose I have an $n\times n$ rotation matrix with even $n$. I want to represent it as a product of $k$ planar rotations, with arbitrary planes.

How big is $k$ in the worst case?
What is the algorithm to obtain this decomposition?

I'm curious if $k$ can be achieved with orthogonal planes of rotation, or whether letting planes be non-orthogonal allows $k$ to be smaller.

You want to read https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03771. There are issues with this paper (such as their proof of Cartan-Dieudonne being incorrect in general), but in the Euclidean case you're interested in these issues don't matter.

I hate to blow my own trumpet, but I'm fairly sure that this old answer of mine answers most (if not all) of your questions: 1) $k=n/2$, 2) a recipe based on (typically complex) eigenvectors is given, 3) correct, the rotation can be written as a composition of exactly $k$ plane rotations (the planes usually not aligned to coordinate axes). With the planes orthogonal to each other (by the inductive process outlined in my post).

Not necessarily calling it a duplicate. At least not yet. Using ideas from Clifford algebra may shed additional light to the questions and/or simplify the algorithms. For example, my suggestion calls for finding the complex eigenvalues by some means.

@JyrkiLahtonen can your recipe be simplified using any of the well-known decompositions? Like Jordan or real schur?

A rotation matrix is always diagonalizable over complex numbers because it is also Hermitian. So sounds like Jordan decomposition is not needed in that sense. I'm afraid I am not familiar with real Schur decomposition.

@JyrkiLahtonen from some numeric experiments, it appears that using RealBlockDiagonalForm option of Schur decomposition recovers planar rotations as 2x2 diagonal blocks

@JyrkiLahtonen I'm suspecting the recipe you are describing is just the standard eigenvalue decomposition -- there are n/2 conjugate eigenvalue pairs, with args theta,-theta. Each pair defines rotation by angle theta in the plane defined by corresponding eigenvectors

@YaroslavBulatov Yes, the standard eigenvalue decomposition of $n \times n$ rotations is necessarily optimal. It's clear that you can always get by with $k = \lfloor n/2\rfloor$ ($n/2$ for even $n$), but the interesting conclusion you come to from Jyrki's answer is that you can't do any better.

Correct. The old answer is just using the real parts of complex subspaces. With a bit of care in combining eigenvectors belonged to conjugate eigenvalues you get 2-d subspaces stable under complex conjugation as well as the rotation. That's all.

Oh! Were you hoping that a lower number of planar rotations would suffice, if you don't insist on the planes being orthogonal? With each planar rotation fixing a subspace of dimension $n-2$ pointwise, the composition will still keep the points of the intersection of those subspace fixed and... (back to Qiaochu's explanation).

This was basically answered in the comments, but to summarize: the answer is $\boxed{ k = \frac{n}{2} }$.
This can be done using either the Cartan-Dieudonné theorem (for a proof see here), which lets you write every element $g \in O(n)$ as a product of at most $n$ hyperplane reflections (if $g \in SO(n)$ then there are an even number of these and you can pair them up to get at most $\frac{n}{2}$ plane rotations, not necessarily orthogonal), or using the spectral theorem, which tells you that every element of $O(n)$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors over $\mathbb{C}$, whose eigenvalues are complex numbers on the unit circle which come in complex conjugate pairs. Given such a complex conjugate pair $\lambda, \overline{\lambda}$ with complex conjugate eigenvectors $v, \overline{v}$, $g$ acts by a rotation by $\text{arg}(\lambda)$ on the plane spanned by $\text{Re}(v), \text{Im}(v)$, so the spectral theorem writes $g$ as a direct sum (hence product) of $\frac{n}{2}$ plane rotations, which are now orthogonal.
A product of $k < \frac{n}{2}$ plane rotations, orthogonal or otherwise, necessarily fixes a subspace of dimension at least $n - 2k$ (namely the orthogonal complement of the sum of the planes of the rotations), but in the general case $g \in O(n)$ does not have a fixed subspace at all. So $k = \frac{n}{2}$ is best possible in general, and is the generic case.
The spectral theorem reduces the algorithmic problem to finding eigenvectors, but I think there is an algorithmic proof of the Cartan-Dieudonne theorem that is even simpler than this and doesn't require even the concept of an eigenvector.

One algorithmic proof of the C-D theorem amounts to simply applying the standard procedure for getting the QR decomposition using Householder transformations (i.e. using hyperplane reflections).
